Get screen resolution with system calls in macOS M1 Arm64
I am learning arm64 assembly and want to make a console game. I got info on how to delay using nanosleep and print some characters into the console.
Now I want to get the width and height of my screen. This is the only resource I have about macOS System calls, but I don't seem to find any one regarding screen resolution.
Please Help.

Use the TIOCGWINSZ ioctl call.

can you brief what it is?

Right.  There are several things to remember.  Your SCREEN is measured in pixels.  What you want (I think) is the number of rows and columns in your console window.  That's not (strictly speaking) an operating system thing.  It's an attribute of the console driver.  That's why you need to make an ioctl request to a file that goes to your console window, like stdout.

Is this something like requesting info from a driver rather than os itself?

@masteronin99 It's an ioctl call that tells you how many rows and columns (in characters) your terminal window has.  See the tty(4) man page.

can you point me to any online course or articles where I can learn this from Start?

I don't use macos myself, but I'll try to write an answer showing you how to use this ioctl call.

To find the size of the terminal window, call ioctl with the TIOCGWINSZ call on the terminal's file descriptor (e.g. file descriptor 0).  This example is in C, but you should be able to translate it into assembly easily.  I would have preferred to show you an assembly example, but I don't have macOS at hand right now to make sure it is correct.
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct winsize sz;

/* get the size of the terminal */
ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &sz);

printf("the terminal has %d rows and %d columns\n", sz.ws_row, sz.ws_col);

The layout of the window size structure is four halfwords, in this order:
ws_row     number of rows
ws_col     number of columns
ws_xpixel  number of horizontal pixels
ws_ypixel  number of vertical pixels

Note that the ws_xpixel and ws_ypixel fields may not be reliable.
When the terminal window is resized, a SIGWINCH (window change) signal will be delivered to all processes in the foreground process group of the terminal.  You can handle SIGWINCH to update your game's knowledge about the current size of the terminal window.  In the SIGWINCH handler, call the TIOCGWINSZ call again to get the updated terminal size.

Thank you so much this works perfectly. After seeing the generated assembly using gcc looks like it is storing some values in registers and branching to the function. But what confused me is that I read somewhere when we are calling an external function in x86 we push the variables into the stack and call it, but how does arm handle this?

@masteronin99 On AArch64, the default calling convention passes function arguments in registers.  Refer to the documentation for details.
